# how resolve Boostrap very slow on localhost?

Tags: apache, bootstrap-5, httpd.conf

I have some trouble with Boostrap . It take 5,0s to load on localhost. But not everytime. Maybe 1 / 3 times.
I import the file from my folder.
I use Chrome but with safari its the same things.

When i use the CDN, there is no problem and the load is fast...
My others files load very fast.
What is very strenge, it take exactly 5,0s to load every time when he is slow.

I precise i desactive the cache, obviously when the cache is enable, there is no problem.

I use httpd from Homebrew a a server.

here are some screenshots
[image: Network from chrome devtools]
[image: Some precision]

Someone know what i can do to get faster ? I very dont know where to start...

thanks to help

P.S. sorry my english is not nice

I try using using XAMPP and his apache but its the same things.

Comment: Hi David, Do you mean it only goes slower when you're using local files rather than CDN? If that is the case I would definitely suggest using the CDN as this is generally considered best practice. The main reason for this is that, if somebody visits your site and loads local files then visits my site a whole set of new files will need to be loaded. If we both used the CDN then the user would only need to load it once.

Comment: Hello, thanks to your answer. I understand that CDN is better for user experience. So I Import CDN and override what i need after. That seem the better things to do. Thanks you